# Rectangle2D não esta atualizando conforme o X e Y do mouse

Tags: java

Ola, sou iniciante em Java, e estou tendo problemas com meu código.
Meu objetivo com ele é que você possa desenhar apenas arrastando o mouse.
As medidas são desproporcionais e eu estou usando um retângulo como caneta, mas não vem ao caso pois é só um teste.

Eis o meu código:
        package Jogo;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Jogo extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {


    BufferedImage backBuffer;
    int janelaH = 500,
        janelaW = 800,
        mouseX = 250,
        mouseY = 400;


    public void paint() {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();

        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(this.mouseX,this.mouseY, 100, 100);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(255 , 255 , 255));
        g2.fill(rect);
    }

    public void iniciar() {
        setTitle("jogo");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(janelaW, janelaH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(null);
        backBuffer = new BufferedImage(janelaW,janelaH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    public void run() {
        iniciar();
        while(true) {
             paint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.mouseX = (int) e.getX();
        this.mouseY = (int) e.getY();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jogo teste = new Jogo();
        teste.run();
    }
}
```